# SSL configuration on nginx - missing .icrt file?

Tags: nginx, ssl-certificate

I've managed to get SSL working on my site, under nginx (or so I thought!). However, I was trying to run it via GTMetrix (to check the new speeds), and it appears that there is something wrong. I talked to their support, and they said:

> Your SSL certificate isn't correctly installed. It's missing the
>   intermediate/chain certificate.

So, I went back to the servers original (Apache) config, and sure enough found this extra line:

```
SSLCACertificateFile /etc/httpd/ssl.crt/wildcard.site.net.icrt
```

I've done some googling, but I'm a bit confused as to how that works with nginx. Everything I have found, tells me that you need to use:

```
ssl    on;
ssl_certificate    /etc/ssl/your_domain_name.pem; (or bundle.crt)
ssl_certificate_key    /etc/ssl/your_domain_name.key;
```

(which is what I have)

Anyone got any pointers?

**UPDATE:** The more I look at it, the more I'm convinced I've got it right already:

[How do I transfer an SSL certificate from an Apache server to an NGINX server](https://serverfault.com/questions/423527/how-do-i-transfer-an-ssl-certificate-from-an-apache-server-to-an-nginx-server)

Yet when running a check on sslshopper.com, I get:

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to combine domain certificate & bundle certificate into one file and reference that as ssl_certificate
like : $ cat www.example.com.crt bundle.crt > www.example.com.chained.crt
refer http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/configuring_https_servers.html#chains

Comment: Aaah thanks - that was it. I was assuming the .key and .cer files on the old (Apache) site were simple download, upload, configure... but I needed to concat the .icrt and .crt files together first: `cat wildcard.steampunkjunkies.net.crt wildcard.steampunkjunkies.net.icrt > wildcard.steampunkjunkies.net.joined.crt`

Answer (score 1):

Nginx wants any chain cert(s) in the ssl_certificate file *after* the server cert. See http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/configuring_https_servers.html#chains .

Link conveniently found on related question [Can't get Nginx to serve correct certificate chain](https://serverfault.com/questions/663332/cant-get-nginx-to-serve-correct-certificate-chain?rq=1) although in that question the actual problem turned out to be different.

Comment: thanks for the reply. I'm not sure what you are suggesting? Mine goes in the order of: `ssl on; ssl_certificate ; ssl_certificate_key` ... are you suggesting it should be in another order?

Comment: @Andrew By "ssl_certificate file" I mean the file used in the ssl_certificate directive. Keep the directive and change the contents of the file to append the chain cert(s). Exactly as the nginx doc at the link shows. I'm pretty sure the order of directives within a block never matters, but it is clearest to stick to the conventional order.

Comment: Thanks Dave. That helped me as well. Eventually, it was the fact I was trying to use the old .key and .crt files - but the .crt file actually needed to be a concat of bundle + inter certificate. I joined them together, updating the config - and not its working a charm :)